# Concavity of function implies convex upper contour

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Today I saw a theorem in class that stated the following:

$f$ is concave $ \Rightarrow\{z \in \mathbb R^n : f(z) \ge c\}$ is convex.

The proof is relatively straight forward and I understand.  However, I have a hard time visualizing this idea to be true.  I try and visualize the idea with a function such as $-x^2$ and I can't seem to see how the upper contour set is convex.  If someone could walk me through a visual example with a graph that would be very helpful.

Comment: In the case of $f(x)=-x^2$, these sets are just intervals, aren't they?

Comment: When I picture the set upper contour set of this function then I picture everything radiating outwards from the function and I see a gap in the upper contour set (namely, the lower contour set), thus I do not see how the upper contour set can be convex if I pick one point from the left and one point from the right of the function

Comment: Consider the example of $f(x) = -x^2$ and $c = -1$.  The set in question is then $\{z\in\mathbb R : -z^2 \ge -1\}$.  What set is that?  Don't consult a visualization (yet); just read the symbols and, if necessary, do some algebra.

Comment: Okay this is helping.  So then I have a straight line at $y=-1$ and all the points $z$, for which $f(z) \ge -1$, is the set, which is a convex set with points from $[a,b] \in \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Perfect.  (It might be a good exercise to work out a formal description of the set you were thinking of at first, to see how it differs from the what's written in the theorem.)

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I will try and do that in the future!

Answer (score 0):

There is a fair chance you may be talking about the set $\{(z, c) \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}|f(z) \ge -c\}$ instead. Now, for a proof of the claim, simply use the definition of convexity via epigraphs.

Indeed,
$f$ is a concave function $\iff$ $-f$ is a convex function $\iff$ $epi(-f) := \{(z, c) \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}|c \ge -f(z)\} = \{(z, c) \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}|f(z) \ge -c\}$ is a convex set.